# split an object based on the field

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

hi i have an object like this

```
var x = {code0: "codefdg", mcode0: "mcodefdg", mcode1: "mcodefdg", comments1: "commentsfdg", code3: "fdg"…}
```

i want to split this object like this way

```
var first = {code0:"codec",mcode0:"microcode"}
var second = {mcode1: "microcode", comments1:"commencements"} 
var forth ={code3: "fag"}
```

is there any way to split like this way?
i try like taking using for loop like

> for(object in x){ }
>   but i don't know what will written in inside this loop .

Comment: is there a pattern on which you base your split ? because it seams pretty random to me.

Comment: ya the object which contain same integer part will in same object

Comment: the code0 and mcode0 have same integerpart (0). so i need these two in same new object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, however i would ouput a hash table:

```
var input= {code0: "codefdg", mcode0: "mcodefdg", mcode1: "mcodefdg", comments1: "commentsfdg", code3: "fdg"};
var output={}
for(var key in input){
 var id=+key.substr(-1);
 output[id]=output[id]||{};
 output[id][key.substr(0,key.length-1)]=input[key];
}
```

So ouput looks like this:

```
{
0:{code,mcode},
1:{mcode,comments},
3:{code}
}
```

Comment: ya .its great!!!! . and one thing . now i get  output key as code0 in output i don't want these integer part how can i remove it?